# Apply function using level

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, pure-function, slot

The following use of Level is documented,  without any example.

[image]

Let's try some simple codes :

```
In[1]  Level[{a, b, c}, {1}, #^2 &]
Out[1]  a^2

In[2]  Level[{a, b, c}, {1}, #1^2 &]
Out[2]  a^2

In[3]  Level[{a, b, c}, {1}, #2^2 &]
Out[3]  b^2

In[4]  Level[{a, b, c}, {1}, #3^2 &]
Out[4]  c^2
```

I want a pure function like ??? in

```
In[4]  Level[{a, b, c}, {1}, ??? &]
Out[4]  {a^2,b^2,c^2}
```

Of course

```
In[5] Level[{a, b, c}, {1}, {#1^2,#2^2,#3^2} &]
```

works but
can it be done without directly referring to the length of the list(=3)
so that it works for arbitrary cases (more complex list and levelspec)?

Indirectly referring the length of a list is OK.

Comment: You can use `{##}^2&`.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I've tried ##^2& and it produced a^b^c^2.

Comment: You nay also try: `Level[{a, b, c}, {0}, #^2 &]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background: `Level[{a, b}, {1}, f]` is `f[a, b]`, `f[#] &[a, b]` is `f[a]`, and `f[##] &[a, b]` is `f[a,b]`.

So in your case, you can use `Level[{a, b, c}, {1}, {##}^2 &]` or `Level[{a, b, c}, {0}, #^2 &]`.